# Dump PgSQL db with PDO

Tags: php, deployment, pdo, dump, postgresql-8.4

I have no CLI access on a server, but I want to run automatic deploy releases and backup/restore data contained by multiple pgsql databases. Is there a way to do this with PDO effortless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Effortless(ly)

No.

You'd basically have to re-implement `pg_dump`. This would not be fun.

You can `COPY` out the tables using [`pg_copy_from`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-from.php). Unsure if there's a PDO equivalent. This will let you dump the data relatively easily, combined with a query against `information_schema` to get a table list.

Dumping the table definitions, users, constraints, indexes, etc, however ... good luck.

Comment: I have a special case, by releases I can generate schema dump on the dev machine. By backup/restore I have an event storage, so I don't need to save so many tables, just one or two I think. Is `pdo::quote()` enough for escaping?

Comment: I don't really understand your comment.

Comment: "by releases I can"; "by backup restore I have an event storage". How is pdo::quote relevant, what "escaping" would you need to do? It seems clear to me that you need to use `pg_copy_from` to dump the table(s) of interest.